# Accessing a div with Class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with Class.
For example

`<div class="button check"></div>`.The css is defined for both 'button','check'. I want to access the above div through jquery and write something in the div.I tried with

```
$('.button check').html("sample data");
```

I do not see anything being written when I run the page.

Please help me.

Comment: It's more standard to write attributes with small letters, i.e. 'class', not 'Class'. Also what I think you're missing is that you are creating two classes: 'button' and 'check'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just chain the CSS classes together, separated by periods:

```
$('.button.check').html("sample data");
```

You will also see better performance in some browsers, by specifying the tag name as well:

```
$('div.button.check').html("sample data");
```

**Update**: After reading [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229600/accessing-a-div-with-class-using-jquery/2229641#2229641), I re-read the original question I realized you might be under the impression you need to use both to reference the `div`. If you had:

```
<div class="button cancel">Cancel</div>
<div class="button check">Check</div>
```

Then chaining selectors (i.e. `.button.cancel`) would make sense. However, if it was the only `div` on the page or you wanted all the `divs` with `button` class, you don't need both classes:

```
<div class="button check">Check</div>
```

This would select it fine:

```
$('div.check').html("sample data");
```

Comment: +1, too fast for me .., and you can also do `$('.check.button')` the order of the classes is not important .. (*as a note to the OP*)

Comment: @Gaby... haha, I always feel lucky when that happens... I am sure you will get me on another question :)

Comment: Additionally, ID routed selectors always perform faster.

$("#header .button.check") for instance.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses.It did work with $('.button.check').Could somebody please explain why i need another period before check?

Comment: Its because each `class` on an element is treated separately. In fact, it might make more sense to you if you viewed `class="one two"` as `classes="one two"` Each one is independent of the other. So, when you want to select a single element using two, you have to chain them together (they both start with a period). If you had an `id`, you would also chain those... only the id starts with `#`: `#myDiv.button.check` -- Though you would rarely if ever use that last selector.. it was just an example.

Comment: @user269527  Without the period (.) it is a element like div, span etc not a class.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just target one class, do you need both?  You can do one class like:

```
$("div.button")
```

OR

```
$(".button")
```

For multiple classes, it could be:

```
$(".button, .check")
```

OR:

```
$(".button").add(".check")
```

HTH.

Comment: @Brian +1 for depth of understanding! I totally missed the possibility that the OP thought both classes were necessary. Nice answer, though the last two examples are a little confusing given the context of a single element presented by the OP.